# Group Value and display data from different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem. I am trying to display total duration and workouts for a phase. I also want on the same time query a related table that stores the exercises for each workouts and displays how many exercises are in this phase:

The text output would be:

```
Phase 1
Duration: 268
Workouts: 6
Exercises: 17

Phase 2
Duration: 245
Workouts: 6
Exercises: 22
```

etc

```
table rk_workouts
id | phase | workout | duration
 1 |     1 |       1 |       45
 2 |     1 |       2 |       49
 3 |     1 |       3 |       48
 4 |     1 |       4 |       41
 5 |     1 |       5 |       42
 6 |     1 |       6 |       43
 7 |     2 |       1 |       41
 8 |     2 |       2 |       40
 9 |     2 |       3 |       41
10 |     2 |       4 |       40
11 |     2 |       5 |       43
12 |     2 |       6 |       40
13 |     3 |       1 |       45
14 |     3 |       2 |       40
15 |     3 |       3 |       40
16 |     3 |       4 |       43
17 |     3 |       5 |       47


table rk_exercises

id | workout_id | workout_name
 1 |          1 | exercise 1
 2 |          1 | exercise 2
 3 |          1 | exercise 3
 4 |          1 | exercise 4
 5 |          1 | exercise 5
 6 |          1 | exercise 6
 7 |          1 | exercise 7
 8 |          2 | exercise 1
 9 |          2 | exercise 2
10 |          2 | exercise 3
11 |          2 | exercise 4
12 |          2 | exercise 5
13 |          2 | exercise 6
14 |          3 | exercise 1
15 |          3 | exercise 2
16 |          3 | exercise 3
17 |          3 | exercise 4
etc
```

I am querying the following:

```
$this->db->qry = "SELECT
                    a.phase,
                    SUM(a.duration) as duration,
                    COUNT(a.workout) as workouts,
                    COUNT(b.id) as exercises
                FROM
                    rk_workouts a
                JOIN
                    rk_exercises b
                ON
                    a.workout=b.workout_id
                WHERE
                    a.category_id = '".$catid."'
                GROUP BY
                    a.phase
                ORDER BY
                    a.phase ASC";
```

I then insert the result into an array:

```
$rlt = $this->db->_result();
if(count($rlt) > 0){
    $new_arr = array();
    foreach($rlt as $dta){
        $new_arr["Phases"][] = array(
            "phase"=>$dta['phase'],
            "duration" => $dta['duration'],
            "workouts" => $dta['workouts'],
            "exercises" => $dta['exercises']
        );                        
    }
```

The result of my array output is not what I expected. I am trying to get the following output:

```
{
    "Phases": [{
        "phase": "1",
        "duration": "268",
        "workouts": "6",
        "exercises": "17"
    }]
}
```

But I get the following:

```
{
    "Phases": [{
        "phase": "1",
        "duration": "1788",
        "workouts": "40",
        "exercises": "40"
    }]
}
```

I am most certain my query is very wrong and wonder if someone could help me out or point me into the right direction. If need to, I can provide full table data.

Thank you for any help and time.

Comment: Remove your  rk_exercises JOIN statement and you'll see that "duration" and "workouts" data will be good. You'll need another query or subquery to count "exercices" without getting duplicates  for "duration" and "workouts".

Comment: @alpadev Thank you for our reply. I have followed your advise and modified my query. I decided to run subquery before the main query, that will SUM all the exercises in my rk_exercises table and then add the number into the rk_workouts table. I added an extra column to the rk_workouts table accommodate the SUM value.

Comment: Sorry. was not the SUM() but rather COUNT() value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new query I am using is before running the main query is:

```
$this->db->qry = "SELECT id FROM rk_workouts";
$mainSQL = $this->db->_execute();
$rlt = $this->db->_result();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mainSQL)) {
    $this->db->qry = "SELECT COUNT(id) as exercises, workout_id FROM rk_exercises WHERE workout_id = '".$row['id']."' ";
    $subSQL = $this->db->_execute();
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subSQL)) {
        $this->db->qry = "UPDATE rk_workouts SET exercises = '".$row['exercises']."' WHERE id = ".$row['workout_id'];
      $this->db->_execute();
   }
}
```

I added an extra column to the rk_workouts Table to store the result of the COUNT(id).

The nain query on my rk_workouts table looks like this:

```
$this->db->qry = "SELECT phase, SUM(duration) as duration, COUNT(workout) as workouts, SUM(exercises) as exercises FROM rk_workouts WHERE category_id = '".$catid."' GROUP by phase ORDER BY phase ASC";
```

The result of my JSON output is now:

```
{
  "Phases": [
    {
      "phase": "1",
      "duration": "268",
      "workouts": "6",
      "exercises": "40"
    },
    {
      "phase": "2",
      "duration": "245",
      "workouts": "6",
      "exercises": "39"
    },
    {
      "phase": "3",
      "duration": "215",
      "workouts": "5",
      "exercises": "32"
    },
    {
      "phase": "4",
      "duration": "225",
      "workouts": "5",
      "exercises": "25"
    },
    {
      "phase": "5",
      "duration": "138",
      "workouts": "3",
      "exercises": "24"
    },
    {
      "phase": "6",
      "duration": "616",
      "workouts": "11",
      "exercises": "80"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is exactly what I needed for my iOS project.
Thank you for everyone involved.